# rails apns for push notifications to apple ipad - which gem to use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apple-push-notifications

I'm looking to push notifications to apple from a rails 3.0.3 application.

I have found a variety of apns"ish" gems including apns_on_rails.

Some of them seem a bit old (1 or 2 years) and it is very unclear what would be the 'current' one to use in 2012.

Can you recommend which one to use given my criteria? Which is mainstream? Which is maintained?
I dislike custom github repositories and am looking for the best stable longer-term gem solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://github.com/PRX/apn_on_rails

We maintain it, and I **just** updated it to now be rails 3 compatible.

You need to add it to your gemfile, and run

```
rails g apn_on_rails:install
rake db:migrate
```

you also need to provide all kinds of certs and credentials, as you would expect, but that is all in the readme.

Comment: +1 Andrew that's great, this is a hot new area so it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

I far prefer [Grocer](https://github.com/grocer/grocer) to APN on rails, its a lot more straightforward and easy to use if you ask me, and doesn't require database migrations or rake tasks to do something thats basically as simple as hitting an Apple server with a formatted JSON...