# How does one go about adding notification center support for a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I spent some time Googling, but I could not find anything that pertained to adding notification center support for a rails app. If a user visits a rails based app/site, how can push notifications be sent to OS X computers that are subscribed to the site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [rails apns for push notifications to apple ipad - which gem to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035290/rails-apns-for-push-notifications-to-apple-ipad-which-gem-to-use)

Comment: No - this is specifically for OS X

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to do [notifications for websites](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/Introduction/Introduction.html), as in Safari Push (server-side APNS) and/or Local (client-side JS) notifications? (link [archive](https://archive.today/6V6Ow))